# Converting array key and values into single variables

Tags: php, html

I know that you can use extract() to achieve this however my circumstances are as followed:

I am building a very small basic MVC framework for personal projects and I have this in my controller:

```php
 public function index(){

    $data = [
      'title' => 'Welcome'
    ];

    $this->view('pages/index', $data);
 }
```

As you can see this passes the data array into the view and you can echo  it like:

```php
echo $data['title'];
```

But I want to echo it like `echo $title;` I know that extract() can do this but that means I have to manually put `extract($data);` at the top of every page which isnt the end of the world but I was just curious if there was a way it could be done automatically? I have tried to use extract by putting it inside the view function but that did not work. I have also tried to use extract by putting it in the header file that is required_once in index.php (thus making the header file a static header thats always required) but neither has worked so any advice would be great.

Here is the code for the view function as requested:

```
public function view($view, $data = []){

      if(file_exists('../../views/'.$view.'.php')){

        require_once '../../views/'.$view.'.php';

      } else {

        die('View does not exist');
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you are using codeigniter, then you can access value of `title` using `$title` in same code.

Comment: is this in Laravel?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra "I am building a very small basic MVC framework for personal project"

Comment: Hi I am not using codeigniter, as good as it is I decided for learning purposes to make my own basic version of an mvc framework

Comment: your own framework? are you following are basic standards of MVC, its looks like CI,

Comment: Can you show us the code of view method?

Comment: Yes I am indeed but bare in mind I am building this for learning purposes primarily

Comment: Added as requested

Comment: Put `extract()` into the `view()` method…!?

Comment: Just put extract() into view()

Comment: I suggest you have to create middleware like, it works between controller and view.

Comment: @deceze  Thank you! I was putting extract in the wrong place in the view function! I needed to put it before the require not after!

Answer (score 1):

Simple that is it ,use compact and extract function

index method

```
 public function index(){


      $title='Welcome';


    $this->view('pages/index', compact('title'));
 }
```

Wiew method

```
public function view($view, $data = []){

      extract($data);

      if(file_exists('../../views/'.$view.'.php')){

        require_once '../../views/'.$view.'.php';

      } else {

        die('View does not exist');
      }
    }
```

In html

```
<h1> hello <?php echo $title; ?></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I belive the issue was sorted I put extract in the wrong place of the view file I put it after the require once not before

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I went wrong, I put extract in the view method before and it didn't work.

However the advice here was to put it in the view function and I now understand that I put the extract function *after* `require_once '../../views/'.$view.'.php';` I just put extract before that line of code and it is now working!